# How to maintain different versions of an Android app

Tags: android

I have a question I cant find an answer to anywhere. Suppose I have an app which basically has some content catering to a group of users. So I have the source code checked into some sort of an SVN , and I have an apk generated which I use as required on the tablet. Now I have a different set of users. The only thing that changes are logos in the app which are images in the drawable folder, language of the app and content within the app. Now how can I dynamically pick the right logo or language based on the user. Based on what I understand I have to build the source code again using the parameters required and generate another apk. Is there no way i can communicate with the apk as to who the user is and it can show the right logo.?  Is there any method kind of  like String_Resources.xml in the .Net world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handling Screen Sizes
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Handling Localization 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

These 2 resources should help. I'm not sure what you mean by 'pick the right logo or language based on the user." Users Device or Users Language??

The system language settings on the users device will determine which language folder to use (if you have them set up as outlined in the second link).

If you want select a logo based on screen size, see the first link. Basically you create identical xml layouts and put them into separate folders like:

layout-normal
layout-small
layout-large
layout-xlarge

then just change the drawable in the xml file for each screen size.

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to generate new apk with new app package e.g.

myapplication.company1
myapplication.company2
...
myapplication.companyN

[This](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/preparing.html) topic may be helpful